# Invalid conversion error in C language

Tags: c, function, struct

I have this function:

```
HOTEL* delh(HOTEL *h  , int *n, int k)
{ 
    int i;
    HOTEL *p;
    for(i=k; i<*n-1; i++)
    {
        h[i]= h[i+1];
    }
    p = (HOTEL *)realloc(h, (*n-1)*sizeof(*p) );
    if (p==NULL) 
    {
        return p;
    }
    *n = *n - 1;
    return p;
}
```

Where Hotel is a struct.When I cal this function in main i got error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'| and error:   initializing argument 2 of 'HOTEL* delh(HOTEL*, int*, int)'|. I did it in this way:

```
case 13:  
    printf("Enter position:  ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    p = delh(h, n, k); //here is the error
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        puts("memory was not reallocated");
    }
    else
    { 
        h = p;
    }
    getch( ); 
    break;
```

Before this i create an array of struct variables.

Comment: the compiler obviously can't read your code because of the horrible indentation.

Comment: upfront it looks like n is `int n;` and what you need to pass is `delh(h, &n, k);`

Comment: `initializing argument 2`..seems obvious. Can you please cross check?

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
p=delh(h, n, k);
```

to:

```
p=delh(h, &n, k);
```